# Storing Web Session on S3 bucket

Tags: php, amazon-s3, amazon

I have a cluster of web servers which store web session related information in a NFS shared directory. We are trying to implement an AWS version of our product where we could use S3 bucket to store static contents.

I now need to store the web sessions on a shared location which all the ec2 webservers can share. As it has been explained here http://harish11g.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/web-session-synchronization-aws-ec2.html, Amazon's Elasticache would be one of the best option to store we b session but it would require some code changes. This is not too much of problem. I am trying to find out what is the best option without changing too much.

Could the S3 buckets be used for storing web sessions? Would there be any issue with latency?  Applications are written in PHP4 and PHP5.